# Is adding two answers playing the system?

Tags: discussion, answers

Adding two different answers to me has a meaning when the answers are both CW, as in the case I am answering a question that is a CW.

Does it make sense to add two different answers, in other cases? Isn't that a way to play the system by getting more votes than what it would be possible by adding a single answer? Clearly, a user cannot vote the same answer twice, but the same user can vote both my answers, and my reputation would be increased of 20, instead of 10.

Supposing that a question contains a sub-question, should I add a different answer for the main question, and for the sub-question? In this way, if I am reporting something that is correct, I could probably get two up-votes from the same user; there could be a user who down-votes one of the answers because the user thinks I am trying to play the system, but as long as there is a user who votes both my answers, my reputation is increased of 18, instead of 10.

Supposing that a question is asking about which module to use for a specific purpose, and there are three completely different modules that could be used. Should I add an answer for each of the possible candidates? Also in this case, if I am sure that all three modules suits the OP's needs, I can count on three possible votes from the same user, instead of getting a single vote. (It could also mean I get three down-votes, and it's not said that the user would necessarily up-votes all the answers I gave, though.)

I don't think that splitting the answer so somebody can down-vote the answer and it would be clear what part of the answer has been down-voted is a reason for adding two different answers; if that would be the case, in many questions we should have the double of the answers we effectively have.

What is the "limit" of adding two different answers that are not CW for the same question, if such a "limit" exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two answers were similar, they could be combined into one answer to explain the similarities.

If the two answers were contradictory, they could be combined into one answer to explain the differences.

I see no reason to leave separate answers.

Comment: mostly correct, but on point #2 if they are radically different, they *should* be different answers so they can be voted on independently.

Comment: In that case, it depends from what _radically different_ means; if the question is about which module to use, and I am suggesting three different modules that are radically different, but they all suit the requirements listed by the OP, I am not sure I should add three different answers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think you should, there is little scope for people to agree or not on a granular level with a combined answer.